# Java - Change Listeners for primitive types

Tags: java, events, primitive-types

How do you make a program execute a set of commands when something happens e.g. a variable changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a primitive wrapper class (e.g. `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Long`, and etc.) and register a [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html). For more information, see [How to Write a Property Change Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, because the code on the java website is a little vague

Comment: @SamanthaCatania, Look at the section "Bound Properties" - [JavaBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

By using a PropertyChangeListener for a JavaBean.

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/343.html

If you have a Swing app you can register the listener but in a different way. (see MRE's response)